# What happens when I increase the exponent and decrease the base?

Tags: exponentiation

Let $y_1=r^n$, where $r>1$ and $n>1$.

Suppose we decrease $r$ and increase $n$ such that $y_2=(r-\epsilon)^{n+\beta}$. If $\epsilon>\beta$, can we prove that $y_2<y_1$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-If $0<a<b$ then $a^x<b^x$ for all $x>0$ and $a^x>b^x$ for all $x<0$.

On the other hand, for all $N>0$ you have $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $$a^{x_1}=b^{x_2}=N$$ You can make your own conclusions (see at the figure).

[image]

Comment: I don't see your point in the figure. $5^x$ will obviously grow faster than $2^x$. My question is about what happens when we slightly decrease the base and increase the exponent. Is the result expected to grow or decay?

Comment: OK, if you cannot see what I wanted to say.

Comment: You really think your answer explains my question?

Comment: Yes, but no problem for me. Regards.